# How to save Dark mode to local storage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".dark_mode_btn button");
const element = document.querySelectorAll("div, h2, html");
    

$(btn).click(function(){
    if($(element).hasClass('dark_mode'))
   {
      $(element).removeClass('dark_mode');
            
    } else{
      $(element).addClass('dark_mode');
           
    }
});
```

My code can't save  when I move to other pages.
How can I save thoes in localstorage?

Comment: store it in localStorage

Comment: You can store the setting of the page in the localStorage. Once you load the page again, you can fetch the setting in the localStorage. [MDN localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's localStorage to save the preference.

You can store a string ('true'/'false') and check on page load.

Something like this will help:

```js
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("dark-mode");
//darkMode will be a string
if(darkMode != null && darkMode === 'true'){
    $(element).addClass("dark_mode");
}
```

use **localStorage.setItem()** to set the value.
Ex: `localStorage.setItem("dark-mode","true");` or `localStorage.setItem("dark-mode","false");`

more info here: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add that in the localStorage using .setItem() method of the localStorage and you can retrieve same using .getitem() method. Please find below code to

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".dark_mode_btn button");
const element = document.querySelectorAll("div, h2, html");
    

$(btn).click(function(){
    if($(element).hasClass('dark_mode'))
   {
      $(element).removeClass('dark_mode');
      localstorage.setItem("darkModeEnabled","true")
            
    } else{
      $(element).addClass('dark_mode');
      localstorage.setItem("darkModeEnabled","false")     
    }
});
// To get the Item use localStorage.getItem('darkModeEnabled');
```

Please make sure to store only string/boolena type data in the storage as it only accepts stringified data.For objects please stringify data using JSON.stringify()

Note : I would suggest to load these values from database instead of storage as you will loose the information once user logout/session-ends or clears the storage.